# footer.php not showing on mobile or tablet

Tags: html, css, footer

This hasn't happened to me before but I'm working on finishing a site(Wordpress) and for some reason that I can't understand, the footer won't display on my iPhone or iPad. When I resize on chrome or use the mobile view in dev tools it's there but not on the actual devices. Hoping someone can give me some insight on what I'm doing wrong because I have a pretty simple setup and I have a feeling it's something silly. The site is http://springstderm.com/

Footer.php code:

```
<footer>
<div class="footer-bg">
    <div class="container">
        <p>Spring Street Dermatology   |   73 Spring Street, Suite 303, NYC   |   212.431.4749  |  <a href="#">Make An Appointment</a></p>
        <p>Copyright &copy;<?php echo date ( "Y" ); ?> Spring Street Dermatology. All Rights Reserved.</p>
    </div>
</div>
</footer>
```

CSS for footer:

```
footer {
    background-color: #4A4A4A;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 40px 0;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 135px;
}

footer .footer-bg {
background-color: #4A4A4A;
}
```

Comment: it shows on my android phone

Comment: Start by fixing the HTML errrors: https://validator.w3.org/nu/?doc=http%3A%2F%2Fspringstderm.com%2F

Answer (score 0):

In my Android (Samsung Galaxy S5) works fine in Chrome and native browser.

Answer (score 0):

It does show up.. It works fine.[image]

Comment: This is so strange. I have 2 different iphones and 2 different ipads at my home that shows a blank white section

Comment: Did you check in browser other than safari?